# autocompletetextview and onitemclick

Tags: android, xml, autocompletetextview, onitemclicklistener

i have implement onitemclicklistener. i have 3 autocompletetextview. i want to get the id(the id which is used in xml file) from which autocompletetextview is clicked.i can solve this with implementing onitemselectedlistener and using spinner. but how can i solve it by implementing onitemclicklistener and autocompletetextview instead of spinner. plz help me... here is the correct code(onitemselectedlistener and spinner ) :

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
     Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;

     if (spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner_select_bus){
        //stuff
 }
 }
```

and here is my error code :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
     AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) parent;
     if (actv.getId() == R.id.spinner_select_bus){
        //stuff
 }
 }
```

i know this is wrong approach because AdapterView cannot cast to AutoCompleteTextView. bt how to solve this......

Comment: cast the View v with AutoCompleteTextView instead of casting parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [an anonymous inner listener class which holds your whole onItemClick-code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743102/2523663) or you can create [a listener class which modifies the onItemClick call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32392355/2306907) in such a way, that the AutoCompleteTextView is passed to the `onItemClick` function.

E.g. your code could look like this:

```
acTextView1.setOnItemClickListener(
    new AutoCompleteTextViewClickListener(acTextView1, this));
acTextView2.setOnItemClickListener(
    new AutoCompleteTextViewClickListener(acTextView2, this));
acTextView3.setOnItemClickListener(
    new AutoCompleteTextViewClickListener(acTextView3, this));
```

and

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
     //v had been modified by AutoCompleteTextViewClickListener 
     //to contain the original AutoCompleteTextView
     AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) v;
     if (actv.getId() == R.id.actextview_select_bus){
        //stuff
     }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32392355/2306907), you'll find the [definition of `AutoCompleteTextViewClickListener`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32392355/2306907)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
   if(parent.getAdpater()==yourAdapterInstance){
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you set an onClickListener to each of the AutoCompleteTextViews in your onCreate method?

Comment: i have set an onClickListener to each of the AutoCompleteTextViews in my on create method which i dont share....every thing is ok....i can get the selected items...but how to get id of autocompletetextview in onItemClick method? @Vexman